# How to fill CSV file with object elements in JS

Tags: javascript, json, csv, thymeleaf

I've got an object and I'd like to put the elements of this object into a CSV file, however when I'm trying to get the key of the object it gives back a type error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

When I console log the object it actually shows all the elements but for some reason I can't get the key and values back.

This is how I console logged the object: `console.log(JSON.stringify(records));`

And here is what I get back: `{"id":"5e7b389911c2125dfaf2b5f2","title":"Example Application Number 1","status":"Ready For Submission","principalInvestigator":"Mr. Harry Styles","coInvestigators":["Niall Horan, Liam Payne, Zayn Malik, Louis Tomilson"],"partners":null,"funder":"Innovate UK","researchGroup":"AHIVES","scheme":"GCRF","requestedAmount":null,"estimatedAmount":1234,"submissionDate":"2020-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00","startDate":"2020-03-29T00:00:00.000+01:00","estimatedDuration":null,"endDate":null,"facility":null,"comments":null,"dateCreated":"2020-03-25T11:55:21.902+01:00","lastUpdated":"2020-03-25T11:55:21.902+01:00","dateDeleted":null}`

Here is the full js function:

```js
window.downloadCsv = function(records) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(records));

    // Use first element to choose the keys and the order
    let keys = Object.keys(records[0]);

    // Build header
    let result = keys.join("\t") + "\n";

    // Add the rows
    records.forEach(function(obj){
        result += keys.map(k => obj[k]).join("\t") + "\n";
    });

    return result;
```

Here is how I parse the object to js from thymeleaf:

```html
 <button title="Downloads the data from the query into a CSV"
                        class="inline-flex items-center bg-red-600 text-white font-bold px-4 py-1
                        rounded shadow hover:bg-red-500"
                        type="submit"
                        th:onclick="downloadCsv(/*[[${record}]]*/)">

                    <span>Download</span>
                    <svg class="fill-current w-4 h-4 ml-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path d="M13 8V2H7v6H2l8 8 8-8h-5zM0 18h20v2H0v-2z" /></svg>
                </button>
```

Comment: It looks like you are treating `records` as an array since you are indexing and using `forEach`, however the stringified example that you included is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you're expecting records to be an array, but it's an object (perhaps one value in the array). Additionally, fields such as `coInvestistigators` are an array, not string, which is a separate case you'll need to handle.

You're accessing `records[0]`, which means you're trying to access `{ 0: <some_value> }` in your JSON object. In your case, `records` isn't an array and it doesn't contain the key `0` so `records[0]` is `undefined`.

`Object.keys` takes in a Javascript object and returns all the keys in an array.

This means that `Object.keys(records[0])` would cause an error since the value of `records[0]` is undefined.

`Object.keys(records)` would return `["id", "title", "status", ...]`